# how to find classes associated given word?-sparql

Tags: dataset, sparql, dbpedia

I want to write a query here https://lod4all.net/sparql.html that finds all the classes associated with a given word. how can I do?

Comment: Please start with <http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask>. It will help if you explain what you mean by "associated with a given word".

Comment: Please answer the following question. What do you understand under the term word in RDF context? RDF is a set of RDF triples, right? An RDF triple is made of resources( identified by URIs) and literals. It doesn't contain something like "word". And next, what kind of relationship (which is basically the predicate of an RDF triple) do you think of when talking about "associated with". That's a generic expression

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to find classes from dbpedia?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48888524/how-to-find-classes-from-dbpedia)

Comment: Asked-and-answered at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48888524/how-to-find-classes-from-dbpedia