# how to find classes from dbpedia?

Tags: sparql, ontology, dbpedia

I need a sparql query that given a free text (user input), 
it finds me from dbpedia all the classes related to it.

How do it?

Comment: please provide more explanation with example of what you have done

Comment: That's a poor question. What means "related"? RDF resources and classes are identified by URIs, thus, you have to create some fulltex-tindex, especially when you want to apply fuzzy matching. Otherwise, you can check whether the `rdfs:label` is an exact match of the user input. The SPARQL query for this is simply as single triple pattern, I guess you'll make it - if not, learn SPARQL

Comment: By the way, you asked the same question on Feb 13 ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48771595/how-to-find-classes-associated-given-word-sparql) and did not answer my comments...I'll vote for close here as it's the same question. No response from you, no answer from my side!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to find classes associated given word?-sparql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48771595/how-to-find-classes-associated-given-word-sparql)

Comment: You might start with http://dbpedia.org/fct/ ...

Answer (score 2):

Also asked [here](https://dbpedia.atlassian.net/wiki/plugins/servlet/ac/com.atlassian.confluence.plugins.confluence-questions/globalQuestionsViewer?ac.com.atlassian.confluence.plugins.confluence-questions.path=/questions/102137857).  Accepted answer said --

> When you say classes, are you mean about types? If yes, try something like
>
> ```
> SELECT ?uri ?label ?type
> WHERE {
> ?uri rdfs:label ?label .
> ?uri <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/type> ?type .
> FILTER regex(str(?label), "Leipzig") .
> }
> limit 10
> ```

I couldn't let this go...

```
PREFIX     rdfs:  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX  virtdrf:  <http://www.openlinksw.com/schemas/virtrdf#>

SELECT      ?s1c AS ?c1 
       COUNT (*) AS ?c2 
                    ?c3
WHERE 
  { 
    QUAD MAP virtrdf:DefaultQuadMap 
    { 
      GRAPH ?g 
      { 
         ?s1  ?s1textp      ?o1          .
         ?o1  bif:contains  '"dbpedia"'  .
      }
    }
    ?s1 a ?s1c .
    OPTIONAL { ?s1c  rdfs:label  ?c3 
               FILTER(langMatches(LANG(?c3),"EN"))}
  }
GROUP BY ?s1c ?c3
ORDER BY DESC (2) ASC (3)
```

The earlier answer gets you partial results.

Comment: Why not `bif:contains`? Why not `rdf:type`?

Comment: @AKSW - No reason. I'm just repasting the answer that was accepted on the other site. I still don't understand what the OP was really looking for.

Comment: Me neither, but the OP never replies. I'll ignore his question in the future. Cheers